# Write a recursive function that returns a stack of Fibonacci sequence

Tags: recursion, stack, fibonacci

My teacher just asked this question in the exam and I have no idea where to go on.
More details, the prototype of function is given as:

```
stack<int> Fibonacci_sequence(int n); //fibonacci numbers count up to n
```

The point is this function is recursive and it should return a stack data type. In my opinion I don't think this is a possible thing to do, but my teacher asked it!!

P.s: sorry, my language is C++

Comment: Write code for this formula: `if(n=0 or 1) then fib(n) = 1, else fib(n) = fib(n-1) +fib(n-2)`. Check this link: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number

Comment: i know how to generate fib sequence but not how to return a stack that contains it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function stack<int> Fibonacci_sequence(int n) {
    if n == 0 {
        var a stack<int>;
        a.push(0);
        return a
    } else if n == 1 {
        var a stack<int>;
        a.push(0);
        a.push(1);
        return a
    } else
        var temp int;
        var seq int;
        seq = Fibonacci_sequence(n-1);
        temp = seq.pop;  
        seq.push(temp);
        seq.push(temp);
        //above: the top element of the stack must be duplicated because it
        //is popped off in the process of calculating the sum.
        seq.push(seq.pop()+Fibonacci_sequence(n-2).pop());
        return seq
    }
}
```

Above is a function that does just that, written in pseudo code because you did not specify a language. Hopefully this helps, it was fun to come up with! Thanks for the interesting question.

Comment: Can you be more specific in C++, because I don't really get the ideas. How can you use: Fibonacci_sequence(n-1).push(Fibonacci_sequence(n-1).pop()+Fibonacci_sequence(n-2).pop());

Because Fibonacci_sequence is just a function that return a stack, it's not a stack right?

Comment: imagine this instead: b = Fibonacci_sequence(n-1) //because it returns a stack right?   c = Fibonacci_sequence(n-2) //now you can do:   b.push(b.pop() + c.pop())  and this is just a longer way of writing what i had above.

Comment: The line:
 return Fibonacci_sequence(n-1).push(Fibonacci_sequence(n-1).pop()+Fibonacci_sequence(n-2).pop());
will cause error because push is a void type then it can not be returned, how can I fix it?

Comment: Ah you are right my bad. Instead do Fibonacci(n-1).push(fibonacci(n-1).pop()+Fibonacci(n-2).pop()) return Fibonacci(n-1) I will edit my pseudo code

Comment: this is my code, it's compiled successfully but it hangs when I run, can you see where the problems are? [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/a3pw5i8wmgt7myu/Source.cpp?dl=0

Comment: I'm on a phone but just looking at it I can say since your stack has a .top() method the first two statements in the else (the ones involving temp) are not necessary. Other than that I can't see anything, perhaps print n out in the function body to see how far it is recursively called.

Comment: It actually does call enough iterations, but no matter how far it goes, it always returns the stack a which contains {0;1}, i think there's some problems in the last return

Comment: ah i made, just a slight change in the last else:
else
 {
  stack<int> b;
  b = Fibonacci_sequence(n - 1);
  b.push(Fibonacci_sequence(n - 1).top() + Fibonacci_sequence(n - 2).top());
  cout << 1 << " ";
  return b;
 }

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify a language, **and** you specified it's an exam, here it is in Ruby.  Ruby provides stack operations for arrays, but I'm only using `push` and `pop` operations in the following so you should be able to easily translate it to the language of your choice.

```
def fib(n)  # no explicit return type, since everything's an object in Ruby
  fail "negative argument not allowed" if n < 0
  if n > 1
    stack = fib(n - 1)
    # grab the last two values...
    f_n_1 = stack.pop
    f_n_2 = stack.pop
    # ...and use them to calculate the next.
    # The value of this expression is the resulting stack, return it
    return stack.push(f_n_2).push(f_n_1).push(f_n_1 + f_n_2)
  elsif n == 1
    return fib(0).push(1)
  else
    return [].push(0)
  end
end

p fib(10)     # => [0, 1, 1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34, 55]
```

You may have to translate this to the language of your exam, but that's appropriate.

Comment: Can you help me work out in C++, I dont really get the part of using container push in that function, it's a function that returns a stack but it's not a stack right?

Comment: I'm not going to write your exam answer for you.  I'm using standard stack operations `push` and `pop`, which are builtin as array operations in Ruby.  This logic should map to any language which offers a stack with `push`/`pop`.

Comment: I did the exam without having this question done :D, I just want to know the answer then.

Comment: The problem is stack<int> fibonacci(int n) is a function, not a stack, how can you use STL containers for it? I Don't really get it

Comment: In that case, I suggest treat translating this as a learning exercise.  `fib` is a function in the code above, I even pointed out in the comment that it doesn't have an explicit return type, but you should clearly see the `return` statements.  I'm not seeing your problem, replace `fib` with `Fibonacci_sequence` globally for an almost 1-1 mapping of what you need.

Comment: If you're not used to chaining methods in OOP, you can explicitly change the `return` into `stack.push(f_n_2); stack.push(f_n_1); stack.push(f_n_1 + f_n_2); return stack`.  Chaining is more concise, though.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my C++ code based on @Elliot pseudo, and it got errors, I specified these errors in the code. And I just figure out that pop() doesn't return a value, I'm gonna fix this.

```
stack<int> Fibonacci_sequence(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) {
        stack<int> a;
        a.push(0);
        return a;
    }
    else if (n == 1) {
        stack<int> a;
        a.push(0);
        a.push(1);
        return a;
    }
    else
    {
        int temp;
        temp = Fibonacci_sequence(n - 1).pop(); //error C2440: '=': cannot convert from 'void' to 'int'
        Fibonacci_sequence(n - 1).push(temp);
        Fibonacci_sequence(n - 1).push(temp);
    //above: the top element of the stack must be duplicated because it
    //is popped off in the process of calculating the sum.
        return Fibonacci_sequence(n - 1).push(Fibonacci_sequence(n - 1).pop() + Fibonacci_sequence(n - 2).pop());//error C2186: '+': illegal operand of type 'void'
    }
}
```

Comment: You don't want to keep calling your `Fibonacci_sequence` multiple times.